# Android java object doesn't match with Wcf Service C# object

Tags: java, c#, android, wcf

I have an android project working with a wcf service. I send an object as a parameter in Select type in java side. But it didn't match with it's C# class. It is always `null` in wcf side.

Here is my Select function :

```
Select select = new Select();
select.setOrderBy(Select.OrderBy.Desc);
select.setOrderColumn("CategoryName");
select.setTop(3);

Where where = new Where();
where.setColumn("ID");
where.setValue("3");
where.setOperators(Where.Operators.GreaterEqual);

jsonObject.put("select", select);
jsonObject.put("where", where);

new TDJson(jsonObject, new TDJsonListener() {
@Override
public void successCallBack(String jsonResult) {
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
        .
        .
        .
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void errorCallBack() {
}
}, true).execute("http://address/Service/Select");
```

This is my TDJson code :

```
try {
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);

if (jsonObj != null) {
    if (!jsonObj.toString().equals("")) {
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonObj.toString(), "UTF-8"));
    }
}

httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/jsonStr");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/jsonStr; charset=utf-8; ");
httpPost.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=600");

HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 3000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 5000);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    jsonResult = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

} else {
    jsonResult = "error";
}
} catch (IOException e) {
jsonResult = "error";
}

return jsonResult;
```

This is my Select class in java :

```
public class Select {
public Integer top;
public String orderColumn;
public OrderBy orderBy;
public String[] columns;

public Integer getTop() {
    return top;
}
public String getOrderColumn() {
    return orderColumn;
}
public OrderBy getOrderBy() {
    return orderBy;
}
public String[] getColumns() {
    return columns;
}

public void setTop(Integer top) {
    this.top = top;
}
public void setOrderColumn(String orderColumn) {
    this.orderColumn = orderColumn;
}
public void setOrderBy(OrderBy orderBy) {
    this.orderBy = orderBy;
}
public void setColumns(String[] columns) {
    this.columns = columns;
}

public enum OrderBy {
    Asc,
    Desc
}
}
```

And this one is my Select class in C# :

```
 [DataContract]
 public class Select
 {
 public Select()
 {
    top = -1;
    orderColumn = null;
    orderBy = OrderBy.Asc;
    columns = null;
 }

[DataMember]
public Int32 top { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public String orderColumn { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public OrderBy orderBy { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public String[] columns { get; set; }

[DataContract]
public enum OrderBy
{
    [EnumMember]
    Asc,
    [EnumMember]
    Desc
}
}
```

And this one is also my wcf code (Select object is always `null` here) :

```
public List<CategoryData> Select(Select select, Where where)
{
Table<Category> table = new Table<Category>();
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed these lines

```
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/jsonStr");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/jsonStr; charset=utf-8; ");
```

to

```
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8; ");
```

and it worked :)